# Copiar y Modificar valor de Input a otro Input, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, entrada

Tengo una duda sobre un código que me esta mantando...

Lo que necesito es que me copie el valor del input en otro input, pero que este sea diferente, es decir sin espacios y en minuscula todo, ejemplo:

Input 1: *Hola Mundo* Input 2: *holamundo* (o *hola_mundo*)

Que copie lo que se escribe en Input 1 en Input 2 pero en minúscula, sin espacios o con guión bajo

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

CODIGO JS:

```
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener('keyup', autoCompleteNew);

function autoCompleteNew(e) {

    $("#name").keyup(autoCompleteNew); 
    var value = $(this).val(); $(this).val = value.toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""); $("#short-name").val(value);

}
```

Les agradezco un mundo, su ayuda con esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar los espacios necesitas una expresion regular.  Para convertir en minusculas usas `.toLowerCase()`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener('keyup', autoCompleteNew);

function autoCompleteNew(e) {            
    var value = $(this).val();         
    $("#short-name").val(value.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="short-name" type="text">
```

Comment: Te agradezco un monton! Funciona de manera correcta, pero una consulta, si necesito que los espacios sean reemplazados por guion bajo solo seria replace(/\s/g, '-') cierto?

Comment: Correcto.  Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: Perfecto, te agradezco!

Comment: Una consulta más, para que en vez de que me elimine reemplace los espacios y lo coloque en minuscula, que tengo que hacer cuando necesito que solo acorte el texto? Es decir ejemplo: INPUT 1: "Texto Largo de Hoy", INPUT 2: "Texto Largo"

Comment: Puedes utilizar `.substring()`.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: Gracias! otra consulta y disculpa el abuso jaja, necesito que verifique si los caracteres del texto estan dentro de la lista de ASCII.. es decir que los caracteres esten solo de la A a la Z sin caracteres especiales (tampoco que este ñ) es para usarlo en URLs